# Check Key Combo Pressed NSIS

Tags: nsis, hotkeys

I'm trying to figure out how to get my NSIS installer to respond to key presses. I thought I would get my answer [here](https://nsis-dev.github.io/NSIS-Forums/html/t-310224.html), but the link referenced in the answer isn't working.

This is what I've tried:

```
!include WinMessages.nsh

Section
  DetailPrint "Starting"
  SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${WM_SETHOTKEY} 1616 0
  Sleep 3000
  SendMessage $HWNDPARENT ${WM_GETHOTKEY} 0 0 $R0
  Pop $R1
  StrCpy $R2 "$$R0 = $R0"
  StrCpy $R2 "$R2$\n$$R1 = $R1"
  IntCmp $R1 0 not_pressed pressed
  
  pressed:
  StrCpy $R2 "$R2$\nPressed"
  Goto end
  
  not_pressed:
  StrCpy $R2 "$R2$\nNot pressed"
  Goto end
  
  end:
  MessageBox MB_OK $R2
SectionEnd
```

I tried running the installer and pressing CTRL+ALT+P and various points, but I never get anything from the stack.  I tried setting the hotkey to `${HOTKEYF_ALT}`, but that didn't make a difference (eventually I'd like to map to CTRL+ALT+F12, but I just want a key combo that works for now).

Edit:

I also tried replacing `Sleep 3000` with

```
  StrCpy $R3 0
  DetailPrint "$$R3 = $R3"
  IntOp $R3 $R3 + 1
  IntCmp $R3 3000 0 -2
```

just in case that line was causing a problem. It didn't help.

Comment: WM_GETHOTKEY is not something you can use to see if the user has pressed the hotkey...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page on the forum you linked to used a custom version of the nsDialogs plug-in, it does not support this by default.

NSIS does not have support for global hot-keys because they are not common in installers.

A global hot-key to focus the installer window is possible but not really that useful:

```
!include WinMessages.nsh

Function .onGuiInit
!define /IfNDef HOTKEYF_CONTROL 2
!define /IfNDef HOTKEYF_ALT 4
!define /IfNDef VK_F12 0x7b
IntOp $0 ${HOTKEYF_CONTROL} | ${HOTKEYF_ALT}
IntOp $0 $0 << 8
IntOp $0 $0 | ${VK_F12}
SendMessage $hWndParent ${WM_SETHOTKEY} $0 0
FunctionEnd
```

The [NsKeyHook plug-in](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/NsKeyHook_plug-in) can handle the WM_CHAR and WM_KEYUP messages so you will be able to perform custom actions when certain keys are pressed but this will only work when a window you have hooked in the installer has focus.

If you don't mind gross hacks, I invented a way to have a global hot-key on a custom page:

```
!include WinMessages.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh


Function onNotifyHack
Pop $0 ; HWND
Pop $1 ; Code
Pop $2 ; pNMH
!define /IfNDef NM_FIRST 0
!define /IfNDef /Math NM_SETFOCUS ${NM_FIRST} - 7
${If} $1 = ${NM_SETFOCUS}
    System::Call 'USER32::SetForegroundWindow(p$hWndParent)'
    MessageBox MB_OK "Hotkey pressed!"
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function myPage
nsDialogs::Create 1018
Pop $0

${NSD_CreateLabel} 0 0 100% 12u "Press Ctrl+Alt+F12"
Pop $0

nsDialogs::CreateControl "SysListView32" ${WS_VISIBLE}|${WS_CHILD} ${WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW} 0 0 0 0 ""
Pop $1
System::Call 'USER32::SetParent(p$1,p0)'
${NSD_RemoveStyle} $1 ${WS_CHILD}
${NSD_OnNotify} $1 onNotifyHack
SendMessage $1 ${WM_SETHOTKEY} 0x067b 0
Push $1

nsDialogs::Show
Pop $1
SendMessage $1 ${WM_CLOSE} "" ""
FunctionEnd

Page Custom myPage
Page InstFiles

Section 
SectionEnd
```

Comment: Your gross hack looks good to me, but I'd like to understand it a little better.  Firstly, what's the purpose of the WS_CHILD style and why does it have to be removed? Also, what's p0 and why is it the parent (rather than p$HWNDPARENT)?  Where is NM_FIRST defined and how did you know the "set focus" code?

Comment: nsDialogs::CreateControl creates a child control but WM_SETHOTKEY does not work on child controls so we make it top-level after it has been created. p0 is NULL (none) parent. It is a bit of a bug that NM_FIRST is not defined but it is 0 anyway. NM_SETFOCUS is documented on MSDN and this notification is used because the hot key will activate and focus the window.